# HSM ZKA control mask values

Tags: security, hardware-security-module

Needed some help on the ZKA security scheme as explained below:

1. In deriving session key, it says to use ZKA master key, random number and control mask. Any idea how control mask value is constructed. I believe its same for all transactions but how is it constructed for PAC?
2. Is control mask and control vector same?
3. In the ZKA algorithm, it refers to a value ‘d’. Any idea what this value means and what to use here?

Appreciate response on the above questions. Many thanks.

I am using this value for Control Vector 00 21 5F 00 03 41 00 00 00 21 5F 00 03 21 00 00